# img src "../" and "./" path url link

Tags: html, image, url, hyperlink, path

In MySQL table I have a row called path. This table contains a path similar to this one:

> ./gallery/1/sweater.jpg

I display the image in index.php using:

```
<img src="" />
```

It works very well. But when a customer choose a category, for an example: clothes, then my program redirect him to the path:

> ./categories/clothes.php

Inside the file clothes.php I want to display the image from database, which is:

> ./gallery/1/sweater.jpg

But I can't do that, because the file clothes.php is in the folder called categories so to make it works the path should be with double dot:

> ../gallery/1/sweater.jpg

But the problem is that in my database there is only one dot like:

> ./gallery/1/sweater.jpg

What is the best way to make it work?

1. I can write a script iside the clothes.php, which adds one dot to the one-dotted path. Isn't it ugly?
2. Do you know more examples? I make very big program in php, which contains thousand of line code for now, but I am stuck with this one simple thing, lol. Thank You for every answer. I accept, ofcourse.

Comment: Make the path relative to somewhere, then expand it when printing through some central function. (BTW, the `img` tag is self-closing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use domain-relative paths, i.e. those starting with a slash.

```
<img src="/gallery/1/sweater.jpg">
```

Comment: That's not an "absolute path", it's a domain-relative path, or "absolute-path reference". A true absolute path would have the full domain and protocol.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar I know, I don't have enough reputation to post comments, if any mod sees this, please move my answer to a comment.

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to be referencing your statically located gallery directory with relative paths. Since you're using PHP, you can create a utility function to get the site root and then append the rest of the path that you're storing in your database. This would work for most cases:

```
$root = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
```

Note: this doesn't handle port numbers or usernames in a url, but you might not need that.